# How to get the original table/column name when using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

With the mysqli extension for PHP, I could use the `fetch_field()` method to get the original (unaliased) names for columns and tables via `orgname` and `orgtable` in the result. PDO provides the method `getColumnMeta()`, but offers no information about the original table and column names; it only returns aliases.

Are there any alternatives to get this information with PDO? I've been thinking about parsing the information from the SQL-query, but I hope there are prettier solutions...

```
SELECT id AS col1, session AS col2 FROM sessions AS table1;
```

Results using `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()`:

```
Array
(
    [native_type] => LONG
    [flags] => Array
        (
            [0] => not_null
            [1] => primary_key
        )

    [table] => table1
    [name] => col1
    [len] => 10
    [precision] => 0
    [pdo_type] => 2
)
Array
(
    [native_type] => VAR_STRING
    [flags] => Array
        (
            [0] => not_null
            [1] => unique_key
        )

    [table] => table1
    [name] => col2
    [len] => 32
    [precision] => 0
    [pdo_type] => 2
)
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the result of calling [`PDOStatement.getColumnMeta`](http://php.net/PDOStatement.getColumnMeta) includes a 'table' column that holds "[t]he name of this column's table as returned by the database." Is this not what you've seen in practice?

Comment: I added the results to my post!

Comment: @d.hill Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [fetch](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php) method

```
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        var_dump($row);
    }
```